# Alpha particle deflection by 180 degree in Rutherford's gold foil experiment

Tags: particle-physics, history

Did some of the aplha particles back trace their path after hitting the gold foil ? (Turn by 180 degrees.)

If so, how were they detected ?

Comment: Sure, some are retroreflected. There are two possible ways to deal with this (I'm not claiming any particular experimenter did so). First, place detectors at $180 \pm\epsilon $ and interpolate; second, put a 50-50 "beamsplitter" in the outgoing path and collect $\alpha$ particles off the splitter path.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you. But I have very less background in physics and am unable to understand what you are saying. Could you simplify that ?

Comment: @biogirl What he said is that some particles are reflected back (retro) and there is detector placed everywhere around foil. It is like they were going around foil with "microphone" and recording how much signal (particles) they get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rutherford's experiment looked much like this:

[image]

([Image source](http://stoichiometricbasics.blogspot.com/2012/06/key-experiments-in-chemistry-part-i.html))

As you can see, the incoming alpha particles hit the gold foil and could scatter in multiple directions, but the detector went around the whole foil (sparing some small region so that the alpha particles could enter the experiment) so even back scattered particles would be detected.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand that the particles which are deflected by angles greater than 90 can be detected by this but I am still not getting how particles deflected at exactly 180 can be detected...

Comment: If there's no detection on the detector, then it must have gone back through the hole it entered.

Comment: Yeah...so how to infer that a deflection of 180 has happened ?

Comment: If you send an alpha particle in and nothing shows up on your detector, then the only place it could have gone is the way it went in.

Comment: But obviously you can't send just one alpha particle (and even if you can, how can you be damn sure about it going back ?)

Comment: Right, so you make the hole as small as possible and just ignore the ones that go backwards exactly 180$^\circ$. The point of the experiment was to see if the plum-pudding model (PPM) was correct. If PPM was right, then there would be no deflections period; if *any* deflections were detected then PPM would be wrong.

Comment: @biogirl Your thinking is correct. In fact it is rarely possible to prove something 100 percent. Especially in something to do with geometry. And your question is how do we know it is exactly 180??? We don't. We just extrapolate it from the fact that there are particles reflected on angles 170, 177 degrees and so on, Approaching 180 degrees as close as perfect you are with your experimentation. Another thing to help you understand this  matter is that there is no IDEA which forbids this to happen.

Comment: @asphir thanks :) could you explain the last line of ur comment ?

Comment: @biogirl What i mean is that there is no visible theoretical reason why this should not happen. No physical law forbids reflection on 180 degrees.

Comment: Just to raise hell-- unless you have a sphere (rather than a circumferential band as in the diagram), you'll miss lots of particles scattered in both $ \theta$ and $\phi$ .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: This is true, but if (A) the distance between the foil and the detector is small enough and (B) the height of the foil is sufficiently large, then the deflections in the azimuth would be detectable.

Comment: BTW, the "detector" in the diagram above was originally a grad student sitting in the dark for a few hours, watching the screen through a microscope and counting flashes... Then move a few degrees and repeat...

Answer (score 0):

Rutherford's law is that the number of scintillations would depend on the scattering angle $\phi$, measured with respect to the incoming trajectory, according to $\sin^{-4}{\phi/2}$. If $\phi=$ 0° (180° according to your way of measuring it), $\sin^{-4}{\phi/2}$ is undefined.

Comment: It is undefined at 0. That implies that it is not possible to have a deflection of 180 , right ??